# Почему не видно Toolbarа?

Tags: android

Создал проект в Android Studio выбрал Empty Activity, тема выбрана AppTheme все по стандарту но Toolbara нет, единственное это добавил еще Basic Activity вот Xml ресурса style

```
  <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

В манифестe тема Activity `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Файл манифеста

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sh_am.learnwords">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/learnicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="android.app.LearnWindow"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_learn_window"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.sh_am.learnwords.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Почему в основном(Empty Activity) Activity нет Toolbar-а?

Comment: Покажите объявления активити в манифесте

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это основное Activity оно открывается с запуском  приложения тема там android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: Ну, раз у вас всё правильно в коде, то, наверное, это опять гугл косячит. Проверьте, чтоб у вас нигде в gradle файлах не было ничего альфа/бета версий.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб их содержимое ничем не отличается от проекта в котором все работало

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что идентичный до последнего знака в файлах проект работает по разному?.. Не думаю, что это возможно. Приведите, всё же, манифест в вопросе - где-то же у вас должно быть отличие от раотающего варианта. Может, правда, у вас InstantRun в студии не отключён и в нём всё и дело.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это может быть из-за добавленного BasicActivity ?

Comment: В MainActivity проблема?.. Если да, то не убираете ли вы там сами тулбар программно? Или может другую тему назначаете? И вы не ответили на счёт того, включен ли у вас InstantRun в студии. И что за BasicActivity?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб InstantRun отключен, проект только создан там только кнопка для перехода на второе активити. Создал проект точно таким же образом все заработало

Comment: Т.е. проблема магическим образом исчезла?.. 0_о

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я новичок, никак не думал что если унаследовать класс от Activity вместо AppCompatActivtiy это может повлиять на Toolbar. В этом дело было. Как они связаны вообще ?

Comment: Не нужно удалять вопрос, если вы сами нашли на него ответ. Лучше опишите как вы решили проблему, написав ответ. Т.е. напишите там, что дело было в использовании активити не из либы поддержки. А проблемы с этим классом из-за желания гугла обеспечивать обратную совместимость. Всё предусмотреть нельзя и поэтому большие различия имеются. Выход - использовать только AppCompatActivity

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ок, спасибо !

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка была в  том что я унаследовал класс от Activity, вместо AppCompatActivity который был выставлен по умолчанию.

Comment: Проблема собственно в том, что при использовании темы из библиотеки поддержки *AppCompat*, корректно отображает `ActionBar` (`Toolbar`) только `AppCompatActivity` (и вообще использование этой темы неразрывно связано с `AppCompatActivity`) . Если использовать какую-то нативную тему (например, *Holo*), то никаких проблем с `ActionBar` не будет и при наследовании от базовой `Activity` и прочих ее наследников.

Comment: @pavlofff только что долбился с Holo, при этом же AppCompatActivity не работает ничего кроме тем из раздела Theme.AppCompat.

Comment: для Holo используйте класс Activity. Слова AppCompat в начале названия класса AppCompatActivity как бы говорят сами за себя - Тема AppCompat - класс AppCompatActivity, нативная тема - класс Activity/

Comment: @pavlofff да я разобрался уже, спасибо. Изначально тупил почему то